# Have error for converting to website from web app

Tags: vb.net

Hi I convert the web app to web site. I follow this link to do it. However I have an error for a few pages which are .ascx and the Global.asax. The error is “Context is not a member of …”. I also exclude the .vbroj file.

I searched the web for fixing the above error and found that link http://forums.asp.net/t/1148374.aspx?Context+is+not+a+member+of+Page+name+
.   Although I did what it said, but the error didn’t go away. Would someone tell me what I can solve the issue.

Summary what I did:

```
1.  Delete the .desginer file
2.  Changed Codebehind to CodeFile
3.  Change the path of the code file with full path within the root directory.
    For example:
  Form CodeFile=" Footer.ascx.vb" Inherits="Testing.Footer"
  To CodeFile="~/Templates/Footer.ascx.vb" Inherits="Testing.Footer"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by deleted the namespace of inherits and change the full path of CodeFile. Also change the full path of @Reference